# What is the best way to filter a large list in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have a table in Excel that I want to filter.  It will have a maximum of 1 million rows and 80 columns.  All the calculations etc are done programatically in arrays to cut dwn processing time.  However, I want to also filter the results to display only certain results based on one column value, followed by a top 5% based on another filter value.

When I first did the sheet, it was limited to 65000 results so there were no problems with the size of the data set.  I just invoked the worksheet filter functions from code and did it that way.  Can I do it that way with a larger data set or is there a way to filter an array the way you d a dataset on a sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Does Excel allow a million rows now?

Comment: Excel 2007 onwards does indeed allow > 1 million rows; 1,048,576 to be precise. However using it to filter data sets that size is not, IMHO, a great idea unless you have a ridiculously awesome PC. Once you get into more than a few thousand records (rule of thumb) I think it's time to move the records into an SQL based database (such as SQL Server or My SQL) and run the queries in that. Handling very large volumes of data is what they live for. Excel... less so. You can do it, but the experience may not be pleasant.

Comment: What code do you have to-date? Are you limited to 65536 cell ranges because you are using the likes of 'Transpose'

Comment: There is a string function `Filter` that you can using with `Transpose` to work on a column (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921350/is-it-possible-to-fill-an-array-with-row-numbers-which-match-a-certain-criteria/13061123#13061123) but this won't handle a filter such as top 5%. You should just try using your current approach,if it takes too long (I'd be surprised), then look outside Excel

Comment: Excel 2007 onwards 2^20 rows. Bit easier to remember. With 1 million rows I would strongly suggest looking at a different solution: database based. You can use Access and the native Jet 4.0 database which will then do the leg work for you. All you need to do via ADODB is pull in the processed data into Excel.

Comment: I would love to use an sql databse, sadly the person I am doing it for knows Excel and so wants everything in Excel- since run time is already over an hour, adding another few minutes for the filtering is just going to be part of the run time.

Comment: The approach you have is the best way to do inside of excel (IMO). The native filtering functions are generally faster than anything you'll come up with via Vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should put that data in an Access table and use [Excel's Database Query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx) to do the job. Since it can also filter retrieved data based on a cell value, it's a great combination.
Storing the data in a database brings you another interesting option (depending on what you want to do): to query your database using [PowerPivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx).

Comment: Yep, a solution I have used elsewhere, sadly here they are insisting on an excel only solution

Comment: I tend to think that when "clients" (or boss) ask for something that's obviously not the right approach, if you come with a clear and gentle explanation of why they will hit a wall, they do listen...

Comment: Yeah, ut here the to include a way for them to edit/add their own functionality.  Since he is ignorant of Access/SQL everything has to be in Excel.  Yep, some people will hobble themselves to maintain a sense of control.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by everyone, excel 2007 will take you to a million rows, but its slower than the excel 2003 that I presume you're using at the moment so filtering using it wouldn't be advisable.

Along with mysql, ms access is also an option.

Comment: Heh, I actually use 2010, client is usng excel 2007 so I just make sure not to use any functionality not supported by 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Although using a relational DB would be preferable in many ways, if you don't have any formulas then filtering your data (1 million rows by 80 columns) using Excel will be reasonably fast (< 1 or 2 seconds depending on what sort of filtering you want to do, which will probably be faster than an un-indexed DB table) assuming that you have enough RAM. 
 If you do have any formulas then you will probably need to be in Manual calculation mode to avoid the filtering process triggering multiple recalculations.

Comment: Yep, manual calculation in most of the application, just turning on automatic calc at the end to get the results across the sheets and trigger some macros