# VBA (Excel): Find Based on Multiple Search Criteria Without Looping

Tags: excel, search, criteria, vba

**I have a large data sheet that I want to search in VBA based on 3 sets of criteria**. Each row entry can be assumed to be unique. The format of the sheet/data itself cannot be changed due to requirements. (I've seen several posts on related questions but haven't found a working solution for this yet.)

At first I used the classic VBA [find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method in a loop:

```
Set foundItem = itemRange.Find(What:=itemName, Lookin:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
If Not foundItem Is Nothing Then
    firstMatchAddr = foundItem.Address
    Do
        ' *Check the other fields in this row for a match and exit if found*
        Set foundItem = itemRange.FindNext(foundItem)
    Loop While foundItem.Address <> firstMatchAddr  And Not foundItem Is Nothing
End If
```

But because this needs to be called a number of times on large sets of data, the speed of this was no good.

I did some searching and found that I could use the [match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx) method with [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581.aspx). So I unsuccessfully tried many variations of that such as:

```
result = Evaluate("=MATCH(1, (""" & criteria1Name & """=A2:A" & lastRow & ")*(""" & criteria2Name & """=B2:B" & lastRow & ")*(""" & criteria3Name & """=C2:C" & lastRow & "), 0)")
```

And

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(resultRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match((criteria1Name = criteria1Range)*(criteria2Name = criteria2Range)*(criteria3Name = criteria3Range))
```

And

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(resultRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match((criteria1Range=criteria1Name )*(criteria2Range=criteria2Name )*(criteria3Range=criteria3Name ))
```

Then I tried using [AutoFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) to sort:

```
.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & criteria1Name
.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & criteria2Name
.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=" & criteria3Name
```

But because one of the sorting columns contains dates, I had issues getting AutoFilter to work properly.

My question is, **how can I search through columns in Excel VBA based on multiple criteria, *without looping*, returning either the row number or the value in the cell of that row that I am interested in**?

Comment: Why are you against looping?  How many rows are you talking?

Comment: What did you wang to do with the returned results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an Advanced Filter.  Put the column headers in a separate part of the sheet (or a different sheet altogether).  Under those column headers, put the criteria you're looking for in each column.  Then name that range (including the headers) something like "Criteria".  Then the macro becomes:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, Range("Criteria")

End Sub
```

As a follow up to my comment below, to have the VBA create the criteria range behind the scenes:

```
Sub Macro1()

    'Code up here that defines the criteria

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Sheets.Add
        'Create the advanced filter criteria range
        .Range("A1") = "HeaderA"
        .Range("B1") = "HeaderB"
        .Range("C1") = "HeaderC"
        .Range("A2") = criteria1Name
        .Range("B2") = criteria2Name
        .Range("C2") = criteria3Name

        'Alternately, to save space:
        '.Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("HeaderA", "HeaderB", "HeaderC")
        '.Range("A2:C2").Value = Array(criteria1Name, criteria2Name, criteria3Name)

        'Then perform the advanced filter
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, .Range("A1:C2")

        'Remove behind the scenes sheet now that the filter is completed
        .Delete
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I can't modify the contents of the workbook in any way, though, and the set of criteria is dynamic based on another set of inputs. I'm really looking for a way to do this exclusively in VBA.

Comment: You could create the criteria range in vba, even create a temp worksheet that will get deleted afterwards, just disable screenupdating and the user will never see the behind the scenes stuff

Comment: I have updated the answer to expand on what I was talking about in my previous comment

Comment: +1 a little easier is to build an IF formula testing fir all three critria, then filtering the True values in a single column

Comment: +1. I've succeeded in filtering the multiple criterias. After I do what I need to do with the filtered values, I would like to be able to unfilter the spreadsheet; however, the filter arrow in the header is not displayed. Is it possible to make it appear together with the filtering? I worked around this implementing another macro with an empty search criteria to filter all rows within the data.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `EVALUATE` for multiple criteria like so to return the row numbers of mathcing values. This uses the same approach as [Is it possible to fill an array with row numbers which match a certain criteria without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921350/is-it-possible-to-fill-an-array-with-row-numbers-which-match-a-certain-criteria/13061123#13061123)

- It searches 50000 rows to match

  - the first four letters in column A matches `fred`
  - the date in B to be greater than `1/1/2001`
  - `apple` in column 5
- Any rows matching these criteria are retuned as row numbers in `x`

(rows 1 and 5 in picture below)

**code**

```
Sub GetEm2()
x = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF((LEFT(A1:A10000,4)=""fred"")*(B1:B10000>date(2001,1,1))*(C1:C10000=""apple""),ROW(A1:A10000),""x"")")), "x", False)
End Sub
```

*`Application.Transpose` is limited to 65536 cells, so a longer range needs to be "chunked" into pieces.*

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to add insert `Dim x` in the code? After having the rows number stored in x, how would you filter these rows? Tks.

Comment: No, X is a variant.

Comment: So yes, he forgot to add `Dim x as Variant`. Always use `Dim`, even for variants.

Comment: But better would be `Dim x() As String` because that is what it returns: an array of strings. Nice one-liner though, +1.