# Excel-VBA - Adding a sheet from a button is working, but not from a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering, can I add an excel sheet using a Macro in a cell that call a Sub method ? Calling the same code from a button works perfectly.

My code crash a the `.Range("A1") = "Col1"` with the wonderful error message `Application-defined or Object-defined error`. I have read that my cells needs to be fully qualified. So I tried replacing `ThisWorkbook` with `Workbooks("MyExcelAddins.xlam")`, but no success.

Is it because when I'm in a cell, the state of the application is not the same ?
I suppose that adding a sheet didn't work...

Thank you.

My code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    .Range("A1") = "Col1"
    .Range("B1") = "Col2"
    .Range("C1") = "Col3"
    .Range("D1") = "Col4"
    .Range("A2") = filter1
    .Range("B2") = filter2
    .Range("C2") = filter3
    .Range("D2") = filter4

    Workbooks("MyExcelAddIns.xlam").Sheets("MyDataSheet").Range("tblMyDataToFilter").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, .Range("A1:D2")
    .Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

**EDIT**
Clarification 1: what I mean by "using a Macro in a cell that call a Sub method" is `=MyFunc(A1;A2;A3;A4)`.
Clarification 2: yes I know that my code is deleting the sheet right away. I wanted to be able to filter a table without looping throught each row and I found this technique in this answer : [VBA (Excel): Find Based on Multiple Search Criteria Without Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764851/vba-excel-find-based-on-multiple-search-criteria-without-looping) .

Finally, I'll mark this post as "Answered", because the comment of David Zemens.

> it is generally forbidden to alter the Excel Environment during the execution of a UDF worksheet function call.

It is the answer I was looking for. Thank you guys.

Comment: Unable to recreate the error whether I run this from an XLAM or an XLSM. Can you please clarify what this means: *using a Macro in a cell that call a Sub method ? Calling the same code from a button works perfectly.* What is a "macro in a cell that call a sub method?"

Comment: Also, it looks like the `.Delete` is going to delete the worksheet that you just added. I'm not sure that is intentional.

Comment: It may be an issue with the newly created sheet not properly being defined.  Try defining `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add` as `Dim nwSht as Sheet: Set nwSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add`.  Then start your `With` as `With nwSht`

Comment: Call from a cell? If you mean your code is part of a Public Function you call like =PFunction(), then I doubt your code will ever work. Please explain how you call from a cell?

Comment: To add/explain @JvdV 's comment: it is generally forbidden to alter the Excel Environment during the execution of a UDF worksheet function call. So if you are expecting that a function evaluation will be able to add a worksheet, this is probably not possible without taking some extraordinary measures.

Comment: @DavidZemens it is what I thought that it was forbidden to alter the Excel Environment. I was just not sure and wasn't able to find the good words to find my answer.

Comment: There is a way to get around this limit, by modifying the approach outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476282/cannot-vba-write-data-to-cells-in-excel-2007-2010-within-a-function/9493006#9493006