# VBA code to delete all rows that do not contain the word "DATE" or numbers "1-31" in Column A?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to combine data from multiple tables on one sheet into one comprehensive table, where every column from each individual table is sorted by column "DATE". How can I use VBA to automatically delete any rows that do not contain the word "DATE" or numbers "1-31"?

I am completely new to VBA code. This is something I was tasked with at my job. I've done lots of googling but have been unable to find any code that does what I need.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines and adjust your question accordingly. People may help you with specific doubts, but does not expect anyone to do your work for you.

Comment: `If [Range].EntireRow.Find("DATE", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then [Range].EntireRow.Delete` is a start. `.Find` will be cumbersome with 32 criterias though. Maybe you could get some ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764851/vba-excel-find-based-on-multiple-search-criteria-without-looping).

Comment: Use a filter, either the regular or advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. This assumes the data to check is in `Column A and B` this will loop through and clear the cell content if matches your criteria and then it maps the empty rows to delete all in one go.

```
Sub DelRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim delRange As Range
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '--> Delete All rows where Cell A and Cell B are empty
        For i = 2 To lrow

            If .Range("A" & i).value = "DATE" Or .Range("B" & i).value = "1-31" Then
                .Range("A" & i).value = ""
                .Range("B" & i).value = ""
            End If

            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).value)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(.Range("B" & i).value)) = 0 Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete

        Set delRange = Nothing

End Sub
```