# How pass vba variables in Application.Evaluate("=IF((LEFT(A1:A10000,4)=""fred"")*(B1:B10000>date(2001,1,1))*

Tags: excel, vba, full-text-search

I need to create a procedure to return the result of a multi search criteria. I found the post below which is an excellent solution, but some details are missing.
How can I pass the variables that define the search to the evaluate statement ?

[VBA (Excel): Find Based on Multiple Search Criteria Without Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764851/vba-excel-find-based-on-multiple-search-criteria-without-looping)
From the Post:

```
Sub GetEm2()
x = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF((LEFT(A1:A10000,4)=""fred"")*(B1:B10000>date(2001,1,1))*(C1:C10000=""apple""),ROW(A1:A10000),""x"")")), "x", False)
End Sub
```

How do I solve this problem ? the code below doesn't work:

```
Sub GetEm2(ByRef myRow As Long, ByVal serch1 As String, ByVal Search2 as String, ByVal search3 as String)
  x = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF((LEFT(A1:A10000,4)=search1)*(B1:B10000=search2)*(C1:C10000=search3),ROW(A1:A10000),""x"")")), "x", False)   
  myRow = Clng(x)
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot by your answers,
JD

Comment: Just as additional side note to evident typo: `serch1` (correct: `search1`).

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the nex way:

```
Sub GetEm2(ByRef myRow As Long, ByVal search1 As String, ByVal search2 as String, ByVal search3 as String)
  myRow  = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF((LEFT(A1:A10000,4)=" & _
                       search1 & ")*(B1:B10000=" & search2 & ")*(C1:C10000=" & search3 & _
                                                  "),ROW(A1:A10000),""x"")")), "x", False)   
End Sub
```

Your code did  not use variables if you use their name as strings inside of a bigger string...

Comment: Took the liberty to correct argument name `serch1` to `search1` :-)

Comment: I din not even look to the spelling... I only 'transformed' the strings (as they were) in variables... Thanks!