# Direct way to put a column in an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to put the values of a column in an array or list, without having to do a for loop.

So basically if I have:

```
Col A
---------
212
411
432
```

I want to put those values in an array or list. This is how I am thinking of doing it, but I don't know the VBA syntax:

1. reference Col A somehow (i.e. myColumn = column("Col A")
2. insert the column values into the array(i.e. myArray = myColumn

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: Because I thought that there could be a more direct way to do this that could me more efficient.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about efficiency unless you're running this over and over again against thousands of rows of data.  The for loop is the way to go.  There is no way I know about to get the data into an array without a loop, and even if there were, it would be looping under the hood anyway -- you just wouldn't know about it.

Comment: I will be running this for a lot of data, that is why I am concerned.

Comment: `arr = Range("A1:A3")` this statement puts the values of range in array without looping. See my answer below.

Comment: @Santosh -- Well I'll be damned.  So it does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim myColumn As Range
    Dim myArray() as Variant
    Set myColumn = Range("A1:A3")
    myArray = myColumn
    For X = 1 To 3
        MsgBox myArray(X, 1)
    Next X
End Sub
```

There are ways to make the size of both the range and array variable.

Comment: Why is MsgBox needed?

Comment: add at the begin `Dim MyArray() as Variant`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Main()
 Dim arr() As Variant
 arr = Range("A1:A3")


For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print arr(i, 1)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, thanks for that I think it works. Two more questions though. How can I see the print statement and if I want to index the array, would it just be arr(1)?

Comment: @user3466555 For loop does show how to print values of array. See this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) may be helpful.

Comment: Note that `Dim arr() As Variant` declares an array of `Variants`. Since a `Variant` can hold an array, that's unnecessary. Instead, use `Dim arr As Variant` and leave the rest of your code the same.

Answer (score 1):

Also when working wth a single column or row, you can use `TRANSPOSE` to create a `1D` variant array, as opposed to the default `2D` array (as Santosh did).

This `1D` method is useful in combination with the `Filter`, `Join` and `Split` functions, such as [Is it possible to fill an array with row numbers which match a certain criteria without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921350/is-it-possible-to-fill-an-array-with-row-numbers-which-match-a-certain-criteria/13061123#13061123)

```
Sub OneD()
Dim arr
arr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3").Value2)
End Sub
```

*or*

```
Sub TwoD()
Dim arr
arr = Range("A1:A3").Value2
End Sub
```