# Attempting to skip blank cells when constructing an array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an array of all the products that my store sells, but in the list, there are an abundance of blank cells that aren't needed when the matrix is good and done. Is there a way to get rid of these blank cells before I construct it?

For my last project, I did

```
Range("A:A").Find("").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

but I don't think that would work for this one because I don't want to mess up the worksheet in any way.

Presently I have this:

```
Dim iRows as Long

Sheets("PR001C2531380000001").Activate
iRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + CLng(0)

Do While Range("A:A").Find("ITEM-NO").Offset(c + 1, 0) = iRows
c = c + 1
Loop

ReDim PrMat(0 To iRows)
d = 0
For d = 0 To UBound(PrMat())
Do While Range("A:A").Find("ITEM-NO").Offset(d + 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row + CLng(0)
PrMat(d) = Range("A:A").Find("ITEM-NO").Offset(d + 1, 0)
d = d + 1
```

I am thinking it's not possible, but even some validation that my thinking is off would be great.

Comment: You could choose Data -> Filter, and de-select the blanks for the column you want to pack. The action does not permanently delete the blank entries and is undone by choosing select all or clearing the filter.

Comment: During the code to iterate through the cells on within the workbook, you could put in code to check that there is data in the cell before adding it into the array.

Comment: Why not just add something like `If Not IsEmpty(Range("A:A").Find("ITEM-NO").Offset(d+1,0) Then ...` and continue then to set `PrMat(d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same technique as [Is it possible to fill an array with row numbers which match a certain criteria without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921350/is-it-possible-to-fill-an-array-with-row-numbers-which-match-a-certain-criteria/13061123#13061123), you can form a 1D array of non blanks as so

```
`form the array
x = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(LEN(A1:A100)>0,A1:A100,""x"")")), "x", False)
`return a 1D string
MsgBox Join(x, ",")
```

Comment: I changed it to `PrMat = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(LEN(A:A)>0,A:A,""PrMat()"")")), "PrMat", False)` 

but it still worked wonderfully, thanks!

Comment: @JohnElias glad to have helped :)