# VBA identify last cell in range in concatenation function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a function that will take a range of cells and return their values in a single cell separated by commas.

So a list of three or four stock tickers would look like this:

```
GOOG, TSLA, APPL
```

The easy way to do this is:

```
For Each cell In rng
    Tickers = Tickers & cell.Value & ", "
Next cell
```

The problem, of course, is that the last value will have a comma which is undesirable.

So I thought it might be possible to include an `If` statement that would change the output for the last cell like this:

```
For Each cell In rng
    If cell = rng.Count - 1 Then
        Tickers = Tickers & cell.Value & "! "
    Else
        Tickers = Tickers + cell.Value & ", "
    End If
Next cell
```

However, this does not seem to be working I assume because `cell` and `rng` are possibly not simple integers so `count-1` doesn't make sense.

So what would be the best way to go about this?  Is there a method for `rng` that would allow the `If` statement to know if the cell was indeed the last in the range?

Comment: After the Loop: `Tickers = Left(Tickers,Len(Tickers)-2)`

Comment: *I assume because cell and rng are possibly not simple integers* - you could start by forcing yourself to declare every variable with an explicit type, by specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of every module. `rng` is likely a `Range` object, and that makes `cell` a `Range` object as well. Kudos for explicitly using `.Value` instead of making a *default property* call, which would have read pretty much exactly as if `cell` *was* a "simple integer".

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know two ways to do this, first is:

```
For Each cell In rng
    times = times + 1
    If times = rng.Count Then
        Tickers = Tickers + cell.Value & "! "
    Else
        Tickers = Tickers + cell.Value & ", "
    End If
Next cell
```

In this case every time you do the loop the variable times increase one, so when times equal to rng.count the first if will be selected.

And the other way is not use For each

```
For cell = 1 to rng.Count
If cell = rng.Count Then
    Tickers = Tickers + Cells(cell,column).Value & "! "
Else
    Tickers = Tickers + Cells(cell,column).Value & ", "
End If
Next cell
```

Where column variable is the number of the column where is the data.

Answer (score 3):

The single best way to *join* a bunch of strings with a delimiter, is to use the `VBA.Strings.Join` function, which requires a single-dimensional array and a delimiter. So you first need to turn your input range into a 1D array.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651439/1188513) explains how to get a 1D array out of a `Range`.

So assuming your input range is contiguous, you can do that and then use the `VBA.Strings.Join` function to concatenate the results.

For example if your values are in `Sheet1!A1:A10`, this one-liner gets you the 10 values separated by a comma:

```
VBA.Strings.Join(Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Value),", ")
```

If the range is not contiguous, then you `Dim` an array using the `Count` of cells in your source range, iterate each cell with `For Each` like you're doing, populate the array, and then your function can return `Join(theValues, ", ")`.

Then, if you want to append an exclamation mark, you don't need to care about which cell is the last one - you just append an exclamation mark to your string and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this....

```
Function CombineCellContent(ByVal Rng As Range) As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim str As String
For Each cell In Rng
    If str = "" Then
        str = cell.Value
    Else
        str = str & ", " & cell.Value
    End If
Next cell
CombineCellContent = str
End Function
```

Then assuming your data is in the range A1:A3, you may use this function like below...

```
=CombineCellContent(A1:A3)
```