# How to create an Array from Range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a function I wrote called 'Contains' to determine if entries in a column of data match a dictionary of 'acceptable' values that are predetermined.

```
Sub Validate_Data()

    Dim My_Dictionary As Variant
    My_Dictionary = Array("Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3")

    Dim Destination As Range
    Set Destination = Range("C2:C10")

    For Each cell In Destination
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = Contains(My_Dictionary, cell)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly fine when I specify the elements of my array, as above. However, when I try to create an array from a range of data, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba) post, my function Contains no longer works

```
Sub Validate_Data()

    Dim My_Dictionary As Variant
    My_Dictionary = Range("A1:A3").Value

    Dim Destination As Range
    Set Destination = Range("C2:C10")

    For Each cell In Destination
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = Contains(My_Dictionary, cell)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Perhaps it is being saved as a different data type in one version as opposed to the other? I can't figure why the first code works and the second does not, and I would rather be able to read the array from a sheet than specify each element in my code (it is much longer than three elements).

Comment: An array created from a range is a *2-d* array.

Comment: Is there a way to create a 1-d array from a range?

Comment: Yes - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649046/one-dimensional-array-from-excel-range) - but I'd suggest modifying `Contains`. Also, perhaps consider naming `My_Dictionary` something else. `Dictionary` at a first glance would make one think you're use a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: Without wanting to distract, _why_ are you doing this?  At first glance I can think of better ways to do this (Lookup, Match, validation)?

Comment: What is the code for `Contains`?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments above, an array created from a `range` is two dimensional. So instead of accessing the elements like `My_Dictionary(x)` it would be like `My_Dictionary(x, x)`.

To get a single dimensional array use `Application.Transpose` on your column.

`My_Dictionary = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3"))`.

---

#### Side notes

@bigben is correct, I was immediately confused because I thought you were working with [`Scripting.Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) object.

I would change that name to something like `acceptableValues` or `acceptableEntries` to make it more clear of what it contains.

Whatever name you do use though I would [remove the underscore](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#underscore--case) from the sub name and variable. This has a special meaning in VBA and can lead to errors for you down the road.